# AsyncTask exception

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

I'm beginner in Android development, I'm working at my fisrt app and I met a problem.
I have to download some images throw internet, and show them in activity.
I have a UI delay until the images are downloaded, so I must use multithreading.

I read more about it, and I think simplest is with AsyncTask, but I recive an exception: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

I need help. Can help me anybody? The code is this:

```
public class Main extends Activity{



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Download download = new Download();
    download.execute(null);
}

private class Download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    ImageButtonOverloaded[] imgView = new ImageButtonOverloaded[24];
    TextView[] textView = new TextView[24];
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{

            URL url = null;
            url = new URL(StaticClass.URL_HOST + "front_page_last_games_plaintext.php");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            initCovers();
            int i = 0;
            Log.d("SYNC", "i = 0");
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                String gameInfo[] = line.split("<NEXT>");
                //Log.d("SYNC", gameInfo[0]);
                //Log.d("SYNC", gameInfo[1]);
                Drawable x = ImageOperations(Main.this, StaticClass.URL_HOST + "resize.php?imagine=" + gameInfo[0] ,"image.jpg");

                Log.d("SYNC", "in while");
                imgView[i].setImageDrawable(x);
                Log.d("SYNC", "in while");
                imgView[i].setGameID(gameInfo[0]);
                imgView[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ImageButtonOverloaded temp = (ImageButtonOverloaded) v;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Single.class);
                        intent.putExtra("ID", temp.getGameID());
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

                textView[i].setText(gameInfo[1]);
                textView[i].setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                textView[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                textView[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                i++;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.d("SYNC", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
    private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
    private void initCovers(){
        imgView[0] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imgView[1] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        imgView[2] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        imgView[3] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        imgView[4] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        imgView[5] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
        imgView[6] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
        imgView[7] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
        imgView[8] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);
        imgView[9] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);
        imgView[10] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);
        imgView[11] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton12);
        imgView[12] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);
        imgView[13] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton14);
        imgView[14] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton15);
        imgView[15] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton16);
        imgView[16] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton17);
        imgView[17] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton18);
        imgView[18] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton19);
        imgView[19] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton20);
        imgView[20] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton21);
        imgView[21] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton22);
        imgView[22] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton23);
        imgView[23] = (ImageButtonOverloaded) findViewById(R.id.imageButton24);

        textView[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        textView[6] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        textView[7] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        textView[8] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        textView[9] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        textView[10] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        textView[11] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        textView[12] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        textView[13] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        textView[14] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        textView[15] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
        textView[16] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
        textView[17] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        textView[18] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
        textView[19] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
        textView[20] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        textView[21] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        textView[22] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);
        textView[23] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doInBackgorund()` is a **non-UI thread** and you cannot access UI elements inside it. The code inside doInBackground() runs on a separate non-ui thread which does not have access to the UI elements defined in your layout. Also, since you are calling another Activity via intents, you should always keep in mind that an Activity runs on the UI thread and hence you should never start another Activity from inside a non-ui thread.

So, remove the code accessing the UI elements from inside of doInBackground() and instead put it inside **`onPostExecute()`**, which is a UI thread and is called after doInBackground() finishes the background processing.

```
int i =0; // global variable
Drawable drawableArray []; // global array to store all the drawables 

doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{

            URL url = null;
            url = new URL(StaticClass.URL_HOST + "front_page_last_games_plaintext.php");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            initCovers();
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                String gameInfo[] = line.split("<NEXT>");
                //Log.d("SYNC", gameInfo[0]);
                //Log.d("SYNC", gameInfo[1]);
                drawableArray[i] = ImageOperations(Main.this, StaticClass.URL_HOST + "resize.php?imagine=" + gameInfo[0] ,"image.jpg");
                i++;
}

onPostExecute()
{
   for(j=0;j<=i;j++)

                Log.d("SYNC", "in while");
                imgView[j].setImageDrawable(drawableArray[j]);
                Log.d("SYNC", "in while");
                imgView[j].setGameID(gameInfo[0]);
                imgView[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ImageButtonOverloaded temp = (ImageButtonOverloaded) v;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Single.class);
                        intent.putExtra("ID", temp.getGameID());
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

                textView[j].setText(gameInfo[1]);
                textView[j].setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                textView[j].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                textView[j].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                j++;
            }
}
```

**EDIT :** As pointed out by *@Luksprog* and *@tolgap*, the image processing part on the main ui thread is alenghty operation and might make the UI unresponsive. So, it would be best to do the image processing on the background thread also and then use onPostExecute() to just set the image bitmaps and update other UI elements. Use a global array to store the Drawables by doing the processing in the background and then just update the UI inside onPostExecute().

Comment: You do realize that the method `ImageOperations` which you moved to `onPostExecute`(on the main `UI` thread) to be run in that `while` loop is a lengthy operation?

Comment: Exactly. The question poster should not implement the code like this, but instead, do all the heavy work in `doInBackground()`, and return the images he wants to set as the `result` to `onPostExecute`. Or, set all the `ImageViews` in the `doInBackground`, and return all the `ImageViews` as a variable to `onPostExecute()` to be set as a contentView

Comment: @Luksprog : Yes sir, I absolutely do! The thing is that I was trying to resolve the error that the question was specifying, though now I realise moving the ImageOperation part on the main UI thread might not be a great idea. So maybe do the Image processing on another background thread and then set the image on the postExecute(). Would that be okay ?

Comment: @Luksprog : Sir, I have modified the code and moved the `ImageOperations` to the `doInBackground` thread. Have a look. Hope it is correct now. Please consider removing your downvote if it is correct now. Thanks. :)